# How to Extract Data from CSV file and import to a Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, csv, split, data-extraction, list-processing

### I'm new in python new developer, just started my intership.
So, I have a csv file with datas customized like that

**Event Category,Event Label,Total Events,Unique Events,Event Value,Avg. Value**

From each row of the file I want to extract the labels of the ports (bellow) in an dictionary and add the total and unic events too. The total and unique events I have to sum them only the ports with same labels (not being dublicate).
My datas look like that :
*'Search,Santorin (JTR) - Paros (PAS) - Santorin (JTR),"2,199","1,584",0,0.00'*
I want my dictionary to look like that :

> data_file = 'Analytics.csv' ports_dict = {
> # "ATH-HER" : [10000, 5000],
> # "ATH-JTR" : [20000, 3500],
> # "HER-JTR" : [100, 500] }

```
 data = 'Analytics.csv'
#row= 'Search,Santorin (JTR) - Paros (PAS) - Santorin (JTR),"2,199","1,584",0,0.00'
def extract_counts(data):
  ports = []
  for i in data.split('"')[1:]:
      ports.append(i.split('"')[0])
  return ports
```

An example from my code is this , when I'm running with the row runs ok when I'm using 'data' it gives me back an empty string. Can Anyone help me with this ?

extract_counts(data)
Out[13]: []

What I have to do to run this for the whole csv
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 'data' is just a string variable. In your loop, you are iterating over each character, not reading a file. Using split on a single character with '"', results in an empty string.

To begin your journey with reading CSV files in Python, I recommend:

- https://realpython.com/python-csv/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html